# Shepherd.js - New instance of the tour on every re-render - auto-trigger tour.start() will use 'dead' instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are using the Shepherd.js 8.3.1 package to create an app tour.
The tour can be manually triggered by an `onClick()` or auto-triggered by a store value `isTourCompleted`

Every time a component, that uses the tour context, is re-rendered a new instance of the tour is created. The new instance is then provided to child components via the context.

We are accessing the tour in several components to read the `isActive()` flag.

```js
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { ShepherdTourContext } from 'react-shepherd'
const tour = useContext(ShepherdTourContext)
```

When we are trying to trigger the tour automatically using an effect, this results in the tour being re-created (the tour ID will change) every time the provider component is re-rendered. Triggering the tour by `onClick()` works fine.

**AppRouter.js** - Mounting point

```js
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { steps } from '../components/tour/steps';
...
const AppRouter = ({ isTourCompleted, ...rest }) => {
  //shepherd tour
  const tourOptions = {
    defaultStepOptions: {
      classes: 'shepherd-theme-introTour',
      cancelIcon: { enabled: true }
    },
    useModalOverlay: true
  };
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router history={history}>
      <ShepherdTour steps={steps} tourOptions={tourOptions}>
        {(!isTourCompleted) &&
          <StartTour autoStart={!isTourCompleted}/>
        }
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinnerFullPage />}>
        <div className="appContainer">
          <Route path="" render={() => <Sidebar />} />
          ...
      </ShepherdTour>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) 
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isTourCompleted: state.userSettings.isTourCompleted
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppRouter)
```

**StartTour.js** Component - Auto starts the tour

```js
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { ShepherdTourContext } from 'react-shepherd'

export const StartTour = (props) => {
  console.log('Shep StartTour props', props)
  const tour = useContext(ShepherdTourContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.autoStart &! tour.isActive()){
      setTimeout(() => {
        tour.start()
        console.log('Shep tour', tour.id, tour.isActive())
      }, 5000)
    }
  }, [props.autoStart])
  return null
}
```

**Sidebar.js** Component - Has an `onClick()` to start the tour

```js
export const Sidebar = (props) => {
  const tour = useContext(ShepherdTourContext);
  console.log('Shep sidebar tour', tour.id)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...
      <p className="tourLinkContainer" onClick={tour.start}>
        <img className="tourLinkContainer__img" src='/images/busStop.svg' />
        <span className="tourLinkContainer__text">{isNavOpen ? "Guide" : ""}</span>
      </p>    
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The console output when updating the `isTourCompleted` flag in the store will be:

```
***INITIAL RENDER***
Shep sidebar tour tour--34d97abe-ea40-43a2-965e-3fd201f272cd
Shep sidebar tour tour--c1f5a161-9fa3-43e4-a109-bcbb0d8a27a2
Shep sidebar tour tour--c1f5a161-9fa3-43e4-a109-bcbb0d8a27a2
Shep sidebar tour tour--c1f5a161-9fa3-43e4-a109-bcbb0d8a27a2
***SET 'isTourCompleted' FLAG IN STORE***
Shep StartTour props Object { autoStart: true }
Shep StartTour props  Object { autoStart: true }
Shep sidebar tour tour--83666ead-d23b-4751-9159-1ef3c1ea0864
Shep sidebar tour tour--83666ead-d23b-4751-9159-1ef3c1ea0864
Shep sidebar tour tour--8a4dce0a-3f9f-40e3-91dc-e23065961e99
Shep sidebar tour tour--8a4dce0a-3f9f-40e3-91dc-e23065961e99
Shep StartTour tour tour--83666ead-d23b-4751-9159-1ef3c1ea0864 true
```

The StartTour component should not use the old instance of the tour.
(the ID should be `tour--8a4dce0a-3f9f-40e3-91dc-e23065961e99`)

When clicking the `< p >` in **Sidebar.js** the correct ID is used (`tour--8a4dce0a-3f9f-40e3-91dc-e23065961e99`).

How can this behaviour be prevented so that the tour can be triggered automatically?